# Best way to find papers in Mathematics by a specific author?

Tags: research

I am a student studying Mathematics. I am looking for papers (in the field of abstract algebra) by a specific author. I wonder if there are standard ways, well-known strategies or methods you frequently use to find theses by a specific author. Any suggestions and recommendations will be helpful.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not willing to name this specific author?

Comment: *Theses* or *papers*? Usually an author has only one thesis.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin No. However, I had no reason to name the author either since  I've been interested in a general situation rather than the particular case.

Comment: @lhf Papers. Thanks for clarifying. I edited my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you mean by "theses"? Two places for finding titles of Ph.D. theses (which you can then google the titles to find possible copies) is [ProQuest](https://dissexpress.proquest.com/search.html) and the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/search.php). For papers and books, you can use [MR Lookup](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup) for 1941-present (if you actually have access to [Mathematical Reviews](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/index.html), then you can pretty much find anything), and [zbMath](https://zbmath.org/) for 1931-present, and [Jahrbuch Database](https://www.emis.de/MATH/JFM/) for 1868-1942, and [EuDML](https://eudml.org/search), and [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), and [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/), and [arXiv.org for math](https://arxiv.org/archive/math). Also, there are quite a few more limited resources for information about mathematicians and papers, such as the [All-Russian Mathematical Portal](http://www.mathnet.ru/index.phtml?&option_lang=eng), and the [MacTutor History 
of Mathematics archive](https://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/), and the [Czech Digital Mathematics Library](https://dml.cz/), and the [French digital mathematics library](http://www.numdam.org/), and [French Ph.D. theses from 1910 to 1949](http://www.numdam.org/thesis), to give just a few of the very many such sites.

Comment: The arxiv is also a good place to start.

Comment: I meant papers. Thanks for clarifying. I edited my post.
Also thanks for many good references to get started.

Comment: @asdq: Thanks. I forgot about that site, and even for such a short list of sites that I gave, arXiv certainly should be included.