# Reference Request - Online copy of R. Graham's "On Finite Sums of Rational Numbers"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, conjectures, egyptian-fractions

Does anyone know where I could find a copy of [Ron Graham](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=6175)'s PhD dissertation, titled "On Finite Sums of Rational Numbers"?

I found [this paper](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/64_01_unit_fractions.pdf), with a similar title, but I could not find Professor Graham's dissertation.

I need to double-check some detail(s) in Professor Graham's dissertation which may not be in the published version. This is in consideration of my [(current) approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4698361/28816) to [odd perfect numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124167) via [Egyptian fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592736).

Comment: This may be better received on MO

Comment: Although some universities have posted scans of their dissertations (e.g. Iowa State, Texas Tech, Michigan State, Univ. of New Mexico, Univ. of Florida, etc.), I do not believe UC-Berkeley has gotten around to doing this. One would think top-ranked universities such as Berkeley, Princeton, Harvard, etc. would be leaders in this, but that's not the case. You can get a copy from [ProQuest](https://dissexpress.proquest.com/dxweb/results.html?pubnum=6413127) and possibly by interlibrary loan from [Berkeley](https://search.library.berkeley.edu/permalink/01UCS_BER/iqob43/alma991021416619706532).

Comment: My profuse thanks, @DaveL.Renfro!  Please post your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698455/reference-request-online-copy-of-r-grahams-on-finite-sums-of-rational-numbe?noredirect=1#comment9942922_4698455) as an actual answer so that I can upvote, and then accept, and so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue.  =)

Comment: Found it!  @Eureka!@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some universities have posted scans of their mathematics dissertations -- [Iowa State University](https://math.iastate.edu/thesis-archive/), [Texas Tech University](https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/browse?type=department&value=Mathematics), [Michigan State University](https://d.lib.msu.edu/search?fq=program_ss%3A%2A&fq=category_ss%3AMathematics) (only a few in recent years), [University of New Mexico](https://digitalrepository.unm.edu/math_etds/), [University of Florida](https://ufl-flvc.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/discovery/search?query=any,contains,%22Dissertations,%20Academic%20--%20UF%20--%20Mathematics%22&tab=Everything&search_scope=MyInst_and_CI&vid=01FALSC_UFL:UFL&lang=en&offset=0), [Ohio State University](https://www.ohio.edu/cas/math/mathematics-research/mathematics-doctoral-dissertations) (only since 1972, and definitely not all for these years), etc. -- I do not believe UC-Berkeley has gotten around to doing this. One would think top-ranked universities such as Berkeley, Princeton, Harvard, etc. would be leaders in an academic service endeavor such as this, but that's not the case. Incidentally, [Caltech](https://thesis.library.caltech.edu/view/option/math.html) is an exception to this observation.

I do not believe there exists a copy online, and maybe not even a .pdf scan held privately by anyone. However, you can purchase a copy from [ProQuest](https://dissexpress.proquest.com/dxweb/results.html?pubnum=6413127) and possibly borrow a copy by interlibrary loan from [Berkeley](https://search.library.berkeley.edu/permalink/01UCS_BER/iqob43/alma991021416619706532).

Comment: This is close to being a duplicate of your [prior answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3206695/242).

Comment: No worries, @BillDubuque.  I perfectly understood.